# How can I use "udhcpc" with "avahi-autoipd"?

Tags: avahi, dhclient

I need the link local address to be acquired by the avahi-autoipd daemon, when the dhcp server goes out of network. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

Referring to the udhcpc documentation, it supports a callout script and will indicate when a lease is gained and lost.  You would need to look at customising this script to call and kill avahi-autoipd as appropriate.

There is no pre-existing integration for this that I am aware of but it would not be difficult.

https://udhcp.busybox.net/README.udhcpc